# Salesforce apex security

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a transaction table which is a custom object.  I want to make an apex that inserts a preset number of records, according to some preset rules - but I don’t want the user to be able to make any transaction records unless they follow these preset rules.

So my solution is to have an apex class that creates some records just as I want them and it’s an instatiable class.  I make a flow and have it call the class and add a button to call the flow. So far so good.  But now anyone can hit the button and run the flow and make the transactions.  I want to control who can run the flow and so execute my apex.  No one has privs on the apex so I can’t work out why it would still run from the flow.  And the users who can push the button do not have change or edit privs on the customer object... so I can’t see why they can make the records

Any ideas please on what’s going wrong and alternatives on how to achieve above would be greatly appreciated  ?

Thanks

Comment: Please show some examples of code that you have tried so far.

Comment: it’s just a class with the @instatiable annotation... so q is how to control who can instatiate it...